# Get the List object to compare with Date Time but am not getting greater values in the List in wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to compare the List Object with Date Time.but getting the same date values also , But I don't want same date time records. I need only maximum date values only.

```
List<ExpImpSurplus_Review> imprtSurplusReview = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpImpSurplus_Review>>(str);
TableName = "Surplus_Review";
lastImpDate = GetLatestImportedTime(TableName);
if (lastImpDate != Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
{
    imprtSurplusReview = imprtSurplusReview.Where(p => (p.DateModified > lastImpDate && p.DateModified != null) || (p.DateCreated > lastImpDate && p.DateModified == null)).ToList();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: please read how write good question ..

Comment: List<ExpImpSurplus_Review> imprtSurplusReview =    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(str);
      TableName = "Surplus_Review";
      lastImpDate = GetLatestImportedTime(TableName);
      if (lastImpDate != Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
      { 
       imprtSurplusReview = imprtSurplusReview.Where(p => (p.DateModified > lastImpDate && p.DateModified != null) || (p.DateCreated > lastImpDate && p.DateModified == null)).ToList();
      }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but I notice two things:

1. `(p.DateModified > lastImpDate && p.DateModified != null)` -- you should be checking for `null` first, i.e. before the first check.  The `&&` operator evaluates from the left
2. `(p.DateCreated > lastImpDate && p.DateModified == null)` -- you're checking for `DateModified` being populated, but you're using `DateCreated` in the comparison, which I assume is a bug.

Comment: but i need to check Both DateModified and Date Created  based on Id DateModified is Null need to check with Datecreated. If Date DateModified is not null check with Datemodified